# Porque essa conta retorna um número negativo?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        console.log(1 - 3 * 2);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu estou confuso no código acima me retornar um número negativo e não positivo porque segue a minha lógica não era para ele fazer primeiro a multiplicação, já que nesse caso a multiplicação vem primeiro, então não era para ele fazer `3 * 2` que vai dar `6` e depois subtrai `1` que vai dar `5`? e mesmo colocando os parênteses para poder forçá-lo a fazer a multiplicação primeiro e depois subtrair ele continua retornando número negativo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        console.log(1 - (3 * 2));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Em vez de tentar fazer arquivos inteiros de HTML auto-contidos pra executar uma única linha de programa, há um prompt interativo de Javascript nos navegadores  - exatamente n console onde você ve a saída de "console.log". Eu sugiro que você brinque um pouco com expressões matemáticas e de string, além de outras estruturas básicas, antes de tentar fazer programas inteiros - o entendimento acontece muito mais fácil.

Comment: Votei pra fechar por ser uma questão puramente matemática, e não de programação em si. Se discorda, por favor faça a sua argumentação aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7731/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo eu votei para fechar com base na interpretação equivocada da comutatividade da subtração nos Reais. Mas o que colocou, fechar por ser uma questão puramente matemática, é procedente pois para se dar uma resposta exata e adequada a essa questão seria necessário uma extensa demonstração algébrica sobre homomorfismo e corpos comutativos que vai muito além do escopo do site

Comment: Quando você multiplica `3 * 2` vai dar `6`, porém você está tirando `6` de `1` é só imaginar uma linha horizontal com números positivos e negativos `-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` quando você subtrai `6` de `1` ele vai cair lá no `-6` no qual esse vai ser o resultado da conta, para poder retornar um número positivo apenas faça o contrário `6 * 2 - 1`.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, o que é algébrica?

Comment: @hkotsubo, não tranquilo!

Comment: @ledeveloper,algébrico é derivativo de algebra, o campo da matemática que estuda as formalidades dos agrupamentos numéricos como conjuntos, anéis, espaços vetoriais, magmas, monoides,... e as transformações aplicáveis a esses corpos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No algorítmo, ele está entendendo que voce está fazendo a expressão

> "+ 1 - 3 * 2"

Primeira coisa que é feito é a multiplicação, por conta da ordem natural das operações

> "- 3 * 2"

que resulta em - 6

Depois ele executa a segunda parte

> "+ 1 - 6"

Que resulta em - 5

Repare que quando a ordem dos números é trocada a expressão dá certo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var res = 3 * 2 - 1;
        console.log(res);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Isso ocorre pela polarização dos sinais.

Comment: Boa explicação!

Comment: Eu só não entendi essa parte `"+ 1 - 3 * 2"`.

Comment: É que não há o sinal, mas o programa considera que se não há sinal, então ele é positivo ou "+".

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente tudo ok com a expressão

console.log(1 - 3 * 2);
[1 - ] 
[3 * 2] => **3 * 2** => 6
1 - 6
-5

você pode pensar nela assim: (1 - (3*2))
Ordem de precedencia de operações matemáticas:

1. Tudo que tiver entre parenteses, chaves ou colchetes;
2. Multiplicações e/ou Divisões;
3. Somas e/ou subtrações.

Comment: Seja bem vindo pixies, sua resposta poderá ser útil, entretanto que tal explica-la melhor ?

Comment: feito! ;) 
ainda novo aqui!!

Answer (score 2):

O motivo é mais simples que parece, nao há nada de errado na conta, ele realmente multiplica primeiro tendo o valor de 6, porém, depois fica assim 1 - 6 que é igual a -5

tenho 100 reais e saco 600 reais removendo do meu limite, meu saldo ficaria então -500 reais `# Exemplo`

```
1 - 3 * 2
1 - 6
-5
```

o correto seria deixa assim para retornar o valor positivo

```
3 * 2 - 1
```